# python issue in connecting to Oracle database

Tags: python, database, oracle

I have this python code where I am trying to connect to Oracle database:

```
def create_database():

    try:
        dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(db_endpoint, port, SID)
        print(dsn_tns)

    except:
        print('ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not create dsn.')
        logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not create dsn.")
        sys.exit()

    try:
        con_str = "username/password@db_endpoint:63000/SID"
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(con_str)
        # conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = db_username,password = db_password, dsn = dsn_tns)

    except:
        print('ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.')
        logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database()
```

`db_endpoint` above is the `host_name`.

As you can see I tried both approaches - forming the dsn and directly using `username/paswword@hostname`.

When I execute the above code I get error DPI-1047:

> 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help.

Is there any error in my code above because of which it is not able to connect?

Comment: did you defined a second `except` statement in your code ?

Comment: @PRMoureu Apologies! By mistake I edited out the `except` from my post above. I have added it back

Comment: you could improve the `except` debugging with `except Exception as e: print(e)` maybe the error message can help you

Comment: @PRMoureu The error I get is `DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help`

Comment: check this [thread](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/55)

Comment: `con_str = "username/password@db_endpoint:63000/SID"`, `db_endpoint` is your string variable holding the endpoint correct? Idk if this fixes your problem but shouldn't be ""username/password@"+db_endpoint+":63000/SID", or is db_endpoint what you masked your actual connection in this post to us?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have 32-bit (not 64-bit) Oracle client libraries installed, and they are in PATH before other Oracle libraries.  The Windows error message "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" is typical of an architectural mismatch.  Alternatively you could use a 64-bit Python with 64-bit Oracle client libraries.

If you are using Instant Client, make sure you have the correct Windows VS Restributable installed.  See the Instant Client page ([32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) or [64-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)) for version information.

Also check the Python [cx_Oracle installation troubleshooting](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#troubleshooting) info.